# ms teams sso node js example bug

Tags: node.js, pug, mean-stack, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

i implemented the sso example for MS Teams: https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs. Everything works well, but now i dont know how i should use it to Authenticate my Mean Stack app. I thought that i need to store the token somewhere, but this isn't possible because the example opens up an pug file from which i couldn't communicate to the node js backend. So how can i handle this problem? How can i create a Token or something, to tell my app that it could communicate?

Answer (score 0):

As per the sample token is getting stored at the local storage and if you want to use it in the Node JS backend then you may try with scripts running in frontend which can help to pass the information to Node JS backend.

You can refer to this sample : [Graph Activity Feed](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs)

Client side we have [authdelegated.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs/static/scripts/auth-delegated.js) and where we are passing the token in request. In [server.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/v-abt/bot-message-with-RSC/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs/server.js) which is node JS file, it is where we receive the same token and exchange it for server side token.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So when i want to use this token in my Angular frontend i just have to get it out of the Local storage? Cause i need it to display user specific content.

Comment: Yes, correct, in frontend you can directly access the local storage and for backend you need to pass it as described previously.

Comment: is there an example how to get the token from local storage? i tried it with document.cookie, but i couldn`t use ist on an different domain.

Comment: doesn`t matter, i found it out. The problem was, that i used ngRok for node.js and angular. But i only got the free version, so the urls not match to each other. i had to set up my localhost with https and need to import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js'; in angular.